# How do I make a gate with only one condition?

Tags: analog, signal, logic-gates, comparator, digital-comparator

I need a simple gate with one condition only but with two ends, if its given 10V it will deliver a square wave from an oscillator I've built, if not then it will deliver a wave from a signal generator, here's what the circuit looks like now:

[image]

The logic I've made is this: if it's more than 10kHz the signal will be attenuated by the filter and the peak detector will give a certain voltage through the comparator, which will deliver around 10V if this condition is met, otherwise it will deliver 0V. Can I make a circuit that if there is 10V in the comparator the oscillator will be the output of the circuit and if not, the signal generator will be the output?

Comment: Do you want an analog multiplexor?

Comment: ohhh it could be, I didn't know that type of circuit

Comment: have you considered using a relay?

Comment: Or feed one into a NAND gate and one into an AND gate and have your control signal common to both?

Comment: hey people, thanks for the answers, the multiplexor I think is a bit difficult because I can't use a 4066 for example, but I will try a relay and the NAND AND solutions.